# How to add tradefed FileUtil dependency into Android app?

Tags: java, android

I have been looking around in many places but I can not find any instructions on how to add the dependency for the [tradefed FileUtil](https://source.android.com/reference/tradefed/com/android/tradefed/util/FileUtil#top_of_page) (**not FileUtils**) in order to use the function getPath() of it. Any help on how to add this into my android application?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Tradefed framework to develop unit tests for Android phone, so I provide my method that how to use Tradefed framework with app. I can't make sure this is what you want, but this might give you some idea.

According to [Trade Federation Docs](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/test_infra/tradefed/fundamentals/machine_setup)

First, build Trade Federation framework from Android source code.

```
$ source ./build/make/envsetup.sh
$ lunch <device-target>
$ make tradefed-all -j8
```

Then, you will get **tradefed.jar** in out/host/linux-x86/tradefed directory, put this tradefed.jar into YourProject/app/libs, and add dependencies in build.gradle(Module:app).

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/tradefed.jar')
}
```

Now you can import com.android.tradefed.util.FileUtil in your app, and use the method getPath() of FileUtil.
[image]